# Is there anything wrong with using loads of virtual elements with knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

Whenever I have a `foreach`, `if`, or `with`, I *always* use the virtual comment-syntax version of the binding.  This is simply because I find it more readable and manageable than inline versions.

I'm worried that there's some kind of hidden cost performance-wise of doing this though.  Is this any (or significantly) less performant than using the traditional non-virtual versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a quick look at the [virtual elements source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/virtualElements.js), it looks like there is a bit of logic that has to collect the enclosed dom nodes and treat them as if they are child nodes (where actually they are at the same level of the dom tree as the comment elements).

Comments are just regular dom elements, so there isn't any fancy/magic parsing of the html to extract them, they are traversed just like any other element.

So, there is a very slight overhead - though I don't think that it's enough to warrant changing your coding style for.